# Method called from another class not working

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have two classes:

`mainGUI` and `preferencesGUI`

I want to call a method in the `mainGUI` class called `updateGUI`, every time the `applychanges` button is pressed. When I try to do it, though, nothing happens.

Here are my classes:

updateGUI:

```
public void updateGUI()
{
    String[] colors = (Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(prefpath), ","));
    int[] colori = new int[colors.Length];
    for (int x = 0; x < colors.Length; x++)
    {
        colori[x] = Convert.ToInt32(colors[x].ToString());
    }
    preferencesGUI pg = new preferencesGUI();
    pg.R1 = colori[0]; 
    pg.G1 = colori[1];
    pg.B1 = colori[2];
    pg.R2 = colori[3]; 
    pg.G2 = colori[4]; 
    pg.B2 = colori[5];
    outputbox.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(colori[0], colori[1], colori[2]);
    outputbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(colori[3], colori[4], colori[5]);
    eventlist.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(colori[0], colori[1], colori[2]);
    eventlist.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(colori[3], colori[4], colori[5]);
}
```

Button click event handler on preferencesGUI:

```
private void applychanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        mainGUI mg = new mainGUI();
        mg.updateGUI();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that mainGUI is already open when preferencesGUI is making this call. So when you do this:

```
private void applychanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        mainGUI mg = new mainGUI();
        mg.updateGUI();
}
```

All you're doing is creating a new instance of mainGUI and then letting it fall out of scope so yes, it does nothing.

This is a pretty common hurdle in GUI development. How do you get the different components to be aware of each other. One approach that people try initially is the singleton. However this can cause issues if you want multiple instances of the component and really it's just kind of messy. A better idea is to pass in the instance of the control but this design isn't very modular since it requires that the preferencesGUI class be aware of the mainGUI class.

Instead you should create an event inside your preferencesGUI like so:

```
class preferencesGUI
{
    // ... Some code ...
    public event Action RequestGUIUpdate;
    protected void OnRequestGUIUpdate() { if (this.RequestGUIUpdate == null) return; RequestGUIUpdate(); }

    // ... Some more code ...

    private void applychanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnRequestGUIUpdate();
    }

    // ... Some more code ...
}
```

So now the preferencesGUI is capable of notifying when a GUI update is necessary. So when you create the preferencesGUI instance from mainGUI attach an event handler like so:

```
preferencesGUI preferences = new preferencesGUI();
preferences.RequestGUIUpdate += new Action(updateGUI);
```

Comment: Great! This worked excellently for me and nicely explained, thanks a lot :D